# How to transfer all apps to a different account?

Tags: google-play-console

I'm aware that on Google Play Developer Console I can request the transfer of a single app to a different account, but the affected account has many apps and I want to transfer all of them.

Is there a shortcut to this, can I somehow request to move **all** apps to a different account?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Have you already contacted Play Console support? From [Transfer apps to a different developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en) Need more help?
Try these next steps:
Contact us
Tell us more and we’ll help you get there

Comment: @Rubén Thanks, I just went ahead to attempt to transfer some of my apps (even when this is all about another account, so just for test purposes) and it lets me select more than one app, indeed. So, my question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

I simply tried to go ahead and transfer one of my apps to see the transfer form and it allows me to add more than one app to transfer:

[image: Form field to add apps]

So it's absolutely possible to transfer more than one app at the same time.